# What happens if i use wait() in child process?

Tags: linux, process, operating-system, fork, wait

Consider de following code fragment:

```
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        if(fork() == 0) {
            printf("%d\n", i);
            wait(0);
        }
```

What will be the result and how many new processes will be created?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(1) is this a homework assignment? - A question about a homework assignment is ok, getting someone to do your homework assignment for you is not.

(2) why don't you try it and see?

(3) if a process itself has no child processes, wait will (immediately) return -1.

(4) Be warned that each child process, after wait(0);, will continue the loop - that is, the parent will fork and the child will print 0; the second time round, both processes will fork, and their children will print 1; the third time round, all four processes will fork, and their four children will print 2, and so forth.

(5) also, be warned that the processes each run independently - the first child may go round the loop several times before the parent does even one, or vice-versa.

If you have a computer to access the internet, you have a computer to try things on - if you are going to be doing C homework in the future, it would be well worth the effort to download a free C compiler for your computer. Try Tiny C at http://bellard.org/tcc/

Comment: (1) sort of; (2) i don't have the means to try it and see :( (3) thanks